# Preserve coloring when using Powershell's Out-Host

Tags: powershell, scripting

I have a command-line executable that prints colored text to standard out. When I do the following...

`my_executable.exe | Out-Host`

...I find that Out-Host removes all colored output. This is a problem when I want to display the colored output of the program without sending it through the pipeline.

Is there another way that allows me to display the colored output of console programs/batch files without sending it through the pipeline?

EDIT:

In other words, what I want is this:

[image: Output with coloring]

But Out-Host causes this:

[image: Output without coloring]

EDIT 2:

Here's why I can't just call my_executable.exe:

I have a script in a .ps1 file similar to the following

```
param($someValue)

# do some things
.\my_executable.exe | Out-Host 
# do some more things
return 1
```

Now when I do the following:

```
$result = .\my-script.ps1
```

$result is 1. If I don't use Out-Host, $result will be the output of my_executable.exe with a 1 at the end. Out-Host allows me to display the output of my_executable.exe *without returning it to the caller*. What I want is a way to display the colored output of my_executable.exe without returning it to the caller.

Comment: Why are you using Out-Host?  From the description: "Because Out-Host is the default, you do not need to specify it unless you want to use its parameters to change the display."  Since you're not using the command parameters, it seems superfluous.

Comment: I'm using Out-Host because if I don't, the result of the command will be fed through the pipeline. In my scripting situation, that's bad.

Comment: Maybe you could use tee-object instead?

Comment: Can you provide an example? I don't know of a way to get Tee-Object to print directly to stdout while bypassing the pipeline.

Comment: As long as it is the last command in the pipeline, then it will simply print the output to the console, in addition to sending it to a file or variable.

Comment: However, that makes it the same as write-output, so I guess there's no point.

Comment: Hmmmm.... this might be helpul.  It talks about cancelling a pipeline:  http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tobias/archive/2010/01/13/cancelling-a-pipeline.aspx

Comment: Can you show how your are using your command line EXE in the pipeline?

Comment: Ok, see edit. Hopefully that example will help you see why I'm using Out-Host in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$exe = ".\my_executable.exe"
$args = ""
$process = Start-Process $exe $args -NoNewWindow -Wait -ErrorAction Stop -PassThru
if ($process.ExitCode -ne 0) {
    throw "FAILED: $exe $args"
}
```

Comment: Of course! All these years and I can't believe I never tried this. Thanks.

Comment: Just found out that in the ISE this does pop a new window, so not perfect, but works for me from powershell.exe.

Answer (score 1):

The `Out-Host` command doesn't support colouring, `Write-Host` does, so I would suggest using that instead.

Alternatively, just get rid of the `Out-Host` business, and just do `$result = .\my-script.ps1 | select -last 1`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However if I use `.\my_executable.exe | Write-Host`, coloring is still taken out. `select -last 1` is a good idea, though it wouldn't work very well if `my-script` was meant to return a collection of objects.

Comment: Well, it's messier, but this will definitely work for you as I use it to color-code my Maven output:
`.\my_executable.exe | %{if($_ -match "^Successful"){Write-Host $_ -ForegroundColor cyan}else{Write-Host $_}}`
And you can chain `elseif`s in order to parse more.